# How to create single table for owned types

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tell me please how to generate single db table for owned types. Here my model

```
public class Price
{
        public string OrderId { get; set; }

        public Money Money { get; set; }

        public Error Error { get; set; }

        public PriceType PriceType { get; set; } // enum

        [ConcurrencyCheck]
        public DateTimeOffset UpdatedOn { get; set; }
}

public class Money
{

        public string Currency { get; set; }

        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

 public class Error
 {

        public ErrorType Type { get; set; }

        public string Message { get; set; }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ComplexType] attribute for Money and Error classes
https://entityframework.net/complex-type

Comment: But I get "The entity type 'Money' requires a primary key to be defined." error

Comment: Do you use 'Money' in fluent api? Something like modelBuilder.Entity<Money>?